# How to get $1$ if number is postitive or $0$, -1 otherwise

Tags: calculus

I have a number $x$ which can be anything (positive, negative, zero, fraction). And I need to get $-1$ if it's negative and $1$ otherwise. Basically the following function:

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1, & x=0\\
\frac{|x|}{x}, &  x \neq 0
\end{cases}
$$

But the function exists only to avoid division by $0$, in case $x=0$ because then obviously $\frac{|x|}{x}$ is not defined.
Is there any way to do the same without defining cases?

Comment: What kind of function are you looking for? Clearly not a continuous one, so a piecewise continuous function seems to be the best candidate. Your proposed definition is already a piecewise function, so it seems "good enough".

Comment: This function is not continuous at 0. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function. So I guess you have to define cases.

Comment: Why complicate with $\frac{|x|}{x}$? Just write $f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1, & x\ge0\\
-1, &  x < 0
\end{cases}$. Any attempt to avoid defining by cases is just going to make work for your readers.

Comment: @TonyK Fair point. I was actually mostly curious if and how it can be done. I agree cases are easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might define
$$f(x) = \lim \limits_{h \rightarrow 0^{+}} \dfrac{\vert x + h\vert - \vert x\vert}{h}$$
but I do think that the case distinction is much clearer (and cleaner).